# nginx domain forwarding with added parameter

Tags: nginx, configuration, dns, server, devops

I keep getting a strange issue on nginx right now. I have two nginx servers, one hosting content that I want to forward to the other server. The one that is doing the forwarding has a sites enabled config of:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name pastdomain.com;
  return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri?from_past_domain=true;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name pastdomain.com;
  return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri?from_past_domain=true;

 # bunch of ssl config here
}
```

Basically I want to send all traffic to the new server where it can get interpreted with a new get variable from_past_domain that I can interpret as needed on the new server.

ie.
pastdomain.com/thing/thing1/1/

would translate to

domain.com/thing/thing1/1?from_past_domain=true

Right now it appears to be working except in the case where I just visit pastdomain.com

I instead get domain.com//?from_past_domain=true

which is incorrect. In addition, it doesn't add new get parameters correctly.

ie. if I have pastdomain.com?test=1&test2=2 it forwards to domain.com/?test=1&test2=2?from_past_domain=true

How can I go about forwarding this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) if you want to change URI. In that case nginx will take care of correct request arguments.

Also, you could [use one server block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server) for HTTP and HTTPS.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name pastdomain.com;

  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://domain.com$1?from_past_domain=true permanent;

  # bunch of ssl config here
  # DO NOT use `ssl on;`
}
```

Comment: It's deprecated. Use `ssl` flag of `listen` directive instead. http://nginx.org/r/ssl